# PHP Curl - 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, curl

I know this is a common problem when using Curl but I have not found a solution after looking through StackOverflow and Google.

I've tried different User Agents and I'm getting different errors:

- The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Requestresource(19) of type (Unknown)
- The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Requeststring(42) of type (Unknown) (I noticed the 42 refers to the '=' in the $target_url)

depending on some of the modifications I make to my code below, however none has pointed me in the direction to solve this problem.

I appreciate any advice:

```
$target_url = "http://www.hockeydb.com/ihdb/stats/pdisplay.php?pid=170307";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($html === false) $html = curl_error($ch);
    echo stripslashes($html);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($ch);
```

*** I should note that I'm actually reading the url (and a few others) from a file, so maybe there is something wrong with the format of the url?
I've done this before and had no problem with it, but now I'm stumped. 
I read each line/url and place it into an array which I loop through later on.

*** If I hardcode the url then it works fine, but for some reason reading it from the file produces the error.

Comment: Little we can offer here for help. You have to compare a working request (probably done using some browser) with the request you send. Use a network sniffer for that best, so that you have the same display for both requests. `wireshark` is an easy to use one.

Comment: that's strange I tried your code on a sandbox and it worked

Comment: anyway try to include Accept headers (encoding and language)

Comment: I also tried it on a sandbox and it worked, however it won't when uploaded to my server. I added a note above, that I'm reading the url from a *.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  `stripslashes()` use `preg_replace()` to filter the URLs

```
<?php
$target_url="http://www.hockeydb.com/ihdb/stats/pdisplay.php?pid=170307";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

$html = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)  ([\"'>]+)#",'$1'.$target_url.'$2$3', $html);
echo $html;

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ch);
?>
```

Comment: The 'stripslashes()' function (or the preg_replace()) is only there for debugging purposes. However, the $html comes back as 'false'.

Comment: The problem actually had to do with reading the contents from the file and not the curl. Apparently each line was appending a newline character to the end of the string which is very strange considering I had made no changes to the php which read it from the file.